# Putting Linux on a Lattice ECP3 FPGA

Tags: fpga, linux, socket, lattice

On my Xilinx Zedboard, I booted Linux from an SD card and then ran a Linux application (written in C) from the SD card. This application created a server using sockets that would return whatever is sent to it. Is this possible on a Lattice ECP3 FPGA? The board I have is an HDR-60.

If its not possible to put linux on the board, is it even possible to transfer data over ethernet to and from a PC?

Comment: The Zedboard appears to contain an embedded ARM, which is what you were running Linux on. It doesn't look like the ECP3 contains an embedded processor.

Comment: @pjc50 but if he implement a softcore processor on his fpga?

Comment: To my knowledge, Lattice doesn't have hard nor soft processors for their FPGA like Zynq's ARM, Xilinx's Microblaze or Altera's NIOS II. To boot linux, you would need to find a soft-processor compatible with your device (like the one from the OpenRISC project maybe) and IP cores to provide the minimal set if peripheral required by the OS. If you can't find somebody who's done that already, you may well be in for a lot of work!

Comment: At first glance it would seem that the question should be if the FPGA has enough resources to make a suitable processor.  But in fact that is not the real question - you can run Linux on any Turing-complete engine.  So the real question is if there is enough memory to store the state and a meaningful amount of software.  Though if you end up having to emulate a suitable processor with something simpler running a complex microcode, performance could be pitiful.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is a stripped version of Linux named ucLinux that is optimized to run on micro controllers without memory management units. It will run on a soft core processor in an ecp3 such as the Lattice provided [Mico32](http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Products/DesignSoftwareAndIP/EmbeddedDesignSoftware/LatticeMicoSystem.aspx).  It will not have anywhere near the performance of the dual core arm 9 in the Zync though.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a task that would take an experenced embedded software engineer weeks to acomplish if not provided by the vendor (Lattice) unless they are very experenced with both embedded Linux (most are) and Lattice (most are not). The tasks involived would include:

- Implementing a micro-processor (either Lattice supplied, or opencores probably has one I have only ever worked with Xilinx)
- Getting the boot loade working (may be as simple as getting uBoot running, may be as hard as writing an assember program to get the c runtime enviroment up, copying over something like grub or uBoot, then configuring that)
- Hooking the Lattice (or other vendor IP) MAC into the kernel (again could be as simple as loading a kernel module or as hard as writing a kernel driver)
- Hooking up the "file system" (ram disk for ease, or flash if you want to deal with drivers for it)

This list is off the top of my head and probably well short of the actual list, and I do this exact kind of thing professionaly. If my boss asked me to do this from scratch I would probably ask for 2-3 months to be "[scotty safe](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Scotty+Principle)"

I hope this give you a good impression of how difficult it could be.